# How to add icons in text in SharePoint Online Communication site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, communication-site, file-icons

I have a page in my communication site in which, I want to add my contact information.

I want to insert icons for it, which should appear before the text.

**Example:**

I want to add **phone number icon** and then type my phone number.

Similar to this one:

[image: Contact Info Icons]

So how to **insert icons** with text **in Modern Experience** ?

Thank you !!

Comment: You cannot add icons directly in **Text** webpart. You may need to develop your own SPFx webpart.

Comment: There is any tutorial to follow up to develop this web part and achieve it ? @Ganesh Sanap

Comment: Yes, there is. Check my answer given below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add icons directly in **Text** webpart. You may need to develop your own SPFx webpart.

You can use Office UI Fabric icons in SPFx webpart as stated in below official documentation by Microsoft:

[Usage of the Office UI Fabric icons in SPFx components](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/office-ui-fabric-integration#usage-of-the-office-ui-fabric-icons-in-spfx-components).

You can find the official documentation of SPFx on how to setup environment and how to build your SPFx webpart below:

[Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).

Comment: So after developing this web part i can add icon inside a textbox instead of using the defaults ones (Bullets & Numbers...) ? @Ganesh Sanap

Comment: SPFx web part is client side coding part. you can do so may things with this. You don't have to use **Text** webpart if you are creating your own webpart. 
You can also make it configurable by creating a SharePoint list with contacts and fetch those contacts in your webpart using custom code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom icons in SPFX webparts then you can convert your image to base64 and set your image src with this base64 code. Like below

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64,iVB...' />
```

---

*If the answer is helpful, please upvote and mark as accepted.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use html encoding of your icons which should work. All available HTML icons can be found [here](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/)